# program to find length of a string

Tags: c, c-strings

If I input string of more than size 10 then why is not generating compile time error as I have declared `str` of size 10? For example I have input `welcome to the world`, then it is compiling and running with no error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0, length;
    char str[10];
    printf("enter string: ");
    gets(str);

    while (str[i] !='\0') {
        i = i + 1;
    }
    length = i;
    printf("the length of string is %d", length);
}
```

Comment: Do not use `gets()`! Use `fgets()` instead. `gets()` is evil and therefore had been removed from C since long.

Comment: "*... why is not generating compile time error ...*" you most likely mean "run-time error", don't you?

Comment: How could it generate a compile time error? You compile your program once and run it an indefinite amount of times. Do you expect the compiler to check a crystal ball to determine if someone is ever going to give an overly large line to your program?

Answer (score 5):

An input string is a runtime entity. Any computation involving it cannot be performed at compile time, so the best you can do is raise a *runtime* error.

Furthermore, `gets` is marked deprecated in C99 and simply removed from C11 because exactly this insecure behavior cannot be prevented: without anyone complaining, you can write beyond array bounds, which is *undefined behavior*. Use `fgets` instead, which provides a higher level of security.

Answer (score 1):

Because `gets` does not take a length parameter it does not  know how large your input buffer is.

you can use `fgets` instead

Answer (score 1):

It is a **undefined behaviour**. Anything can happen.

Never use `gets()` because it does not prevent buffer overflowing which is what your program is doing. Use `fgets()` instead of `gets()`.

`fgets()` prevent the size of array beyond that.

```
fgets(array, sizeOfArray, stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined the string length as 10, so if the value increases the program stops executing, moreover you have not made handling error mechanism for the code. So resulting the following error you mentioned. Use `fgets`

Comment: _the program stops executing_ ... or not, UB is UB

Comment: It should stop executing

Comment: "*... resulting the following error you mentioned.*" which error?

Comment: compile time error he mentioned

Comment: @Balaji.J.B - *"It should stop executing"* If the world was this perfect we wouldn't have to worry about buffer overrun attacks.

Comment: @Balaji.J.B, nops, it can stop executing ... or can continue and eat your cat, thats why its called Undefined Behaviour